# Excel VBA compile error: expected sub, function, or property

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code which shows the texts of name, contact person, address, contact number, email and product order onto a worksheet, but i keep getting this compile error when after entering all the information into a userform and clicking OK, note: all the coding is on the OK command button.

```
Private Sub cmdok_Click()
    'activate worksheet
    Worksheets("CustomersOrders").Activate
    'check if row empty
    NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    Cells(NextRow, 1) = txtName.Text
    Cells(NextRow, 2) = txtperson.Text
    Cells(NextRow, 3) = txtaddress.Text
    Cells(NextRow, 4) = txtcontact.Text
    Cells(NextRow, 5) = txtemail.Text
    Cells(NextRow, 6) = txtorder.Text

    If optYes Then
        Worksheets("SupportInfo").Activate
        NextRow
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA (Range("A:A")) + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1) = txtName.Text
        Cells(NextRow, 2) = txtperson.Text
        Cells(NextRow, 3) = txtaddress
        Cells(NextRow, 4) = txtcontact.Text
        Cells(NextRow, 5) = txtemail.Text
        Cells(NextRow, 6) = txtorder.Text
        Cells(NextRow, 7) = txtdeldate.Text
    End If

    'clear the controls for next entry and set focus to Name
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtperson.Text = ""
    txtaddress.Text = ""
    txtcontact.Text = ""
    txtemail.Text = ""
    txtorder.Text = ""
    txtdeldate.Text = ""
    txtName.SetFocus

    'hide the worksheets
    Worksheets("CustomersOrders").Visible = False
    Worksheets("SupportInfo").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: A compile error should highlight the culprit line and/or give you a message. Why not sharing those informations ?

Comment: I don't see your variables declarations. Don't you use `Option Explicit` ? You definitely shouls (must).

Comment: What is **optYes**? Is it a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your attempt to call NextRow as if it were a function inside the IF statement. You probably wanted:

```
NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA (Range("A:A")) + 1
```

Note: I edited your question to format the code correctly, so this is assuming the assignment is actually missing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264699%28v=office.15%29.aspx). I'd suggest to debug the program (using F8) to find out which line causes the error. As i mentioned in comment, i suspect that **optYes** is a CheckBox control and you can't use it this way. You need to check **Value** property:

```
If optYes.Value then 
'your code
End If
```

Other possible issues:

1) you can't activate worksheet which **Visible** property has been set to **false**, you need to change its visibility

```
'earlier
Worksheets("CustomersOrders").Visible = False
'later
Worksheets("CustomersOrders").Visible = True
Worksheets("CustomersOrders").Activate
```

2) your code does not guarantee that **NextRow** will return proper (first empty) row; rather than it, use function:

```
Public Function GetNextEmptyRow(wsh As Worksheet, Optional sDefCol As String = "A") As Long
    GetNextEmptyRow = wsh.Range(sDefCol & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row +1
End Function

'call
Dim nextRow As Long 

nextRow = GetNextEmptyRow(Worksheets("CustomersOrders"))
```

3) i'd suggest to use [ADODB](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819?wa=wsignin1.0) to provide [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations on data stored in Excel sheet(s).

Cheers,
Maciej